# Github and react.js both display differently

Tags: reactjs, git, github

Currently, I have a problem with React.js and Github. whereby when I launch my website on vscode everything looks fine and all the images able to display. If I use the GitHub URL to view my website, the website is able to load but the images I store in my file don't appear.

Link to GitHub:
https://github.com/stevenleesf/UOWMReact

Vscode
[image]

Github Url : https://stevenleesf.github.io/UOWMReact/
[image]

I think in my homepages in my package.json

```
"homepage": "http://stevenleesf.github.io/UOWMReact/",
```

is accusing the problem because, when I inspect my website, there is two UOWMReact. accusing the problem.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because it is trying to get the assets from `http://stevenleesf.github.io/UOWMReact/UOWMReact/` instead of `http://stevenleesf.github.io/UOWMReact/`

So probably you are referencing your images to `/UOWMReact` subpath at your img src attribute.

Since you already declared `UOWMReact` at your package.json homepage, you don't need to add this subpath to your src attribute.

so you can fix it by changing from:

`<img src="./UOWMReact/images/kdu.png"></img>`

to:

`<img src="./images/kdu.png"></img>`

Comment: Ya this works :D, is there a way to redeclared my homepage in package.json, I try removing UOWMReact from my homepage. and then when I push request it. the website does not appear. What appears is the "read me" document from GitHub.

Comment: You can create a repository with the name "stevenleesf.github.io" when you create it, GitHub Pages will provide it without putting the repository name in the url.

So your webiste will be provided at  `http://stevenleesf.github.io` and your package.json will be `"homepage": "http://stevenleesf.github.io/"